# Excel : get value of intersecting cell if two conditions are matching

Tags: arrays, excel, conditional-statements

I need result value in M2 cell of intersection of M column and row 8 where M1 found in D:D range and A2 found in A2(+1):A500 as shown on attached image. Please help.

[Problem Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTCb0.jpg)

Comment: Is column B empty all the way down to B500?

Comment: Row 1 is date & time stamp. Column A is folders. Column B is empty. I missed to delete it.

Comment: You should combine the value in column A with the value in column D. Put =A2&D2  into B2 and copy it down to row 500. Then you can use MATCH and INDEX to locate A2&M1.